# Binding KeyFieldName from gridview to Url.Action inside column settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

Im trying to get Objects keyfield value to a RouteValueDictionary inside column settings, However for some reason i can only access the field bound to the column inside this call!

Code:

```
    @Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
        {
            //General settings
            settings.Name = "name";
            settings.KeyFieldName = "ID";
            //Other settings etc.....

            settings.Columns.Add(column =>
            {
                column.Name = "Name";
                column.FieldName = "CurrentFieldBoundToColumn";
                column.Caption = "Some caption";

                //Set hyperlink
                column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.HyperLink;
                var hyperLinkProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as HyperLinkProperties;
                String urlFormatString = Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new RouteValueDictionary(new { ID= "{0}" }));
                hyperLinkProperties.NavigateUrlFormatString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(urlFormatString);


            });
    //Other Columns etc etc
 });
```

{ ID= "{0}" }))    This is where i need the Keyfield value however whatever i try i only get the value bound to the column column.FieldName = "CurrentFieldBoundToColumn". Anny ideas?

EDIT;

Got it woorking like so :

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.Name = "Name";
    column.FieldName = "CurrentFieldBoundToColumn"";
    column.Caption = "SomeCaption";

    //Set hyperlink
    column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(content =>
    ViewContext.Writer.Write
    (
        Html.ActionLink
        (
            linkText: content.Text, 
            actionName: "Action", 
            controllerName: "Controller",
            routeValues: new { ID = content.KeyValue }, 
            htmlAttributes: null
        )
    ));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SetDataItemTemplateContent](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcMVCxGridViewColumn_SetDataItemTemplateContenttopic2592) method with a simple [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and [GridViewBaseRowTemplateContainer.KeyValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewBaseRowTemplateContainer_KeyValuetopic) property:

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    //General settings
    settings.Name = "name";
    settings.KeyFieldName = "ID";
    //Other settings etc.....

    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Name = "Name";
        column.FieldName = "CurrentFieldBoundToColumn";
        column.Caption = "Some caption";

        column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(content =>
            ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                Html.ActionLink(content.Text, "Action", "Controller",
                new { ID = content.KeyValue }, null)));
    });
    //Other Columns etc etc
});
```

Comment: Thank you this woorks, However ""LinkText""  in the actionlink Overwrites the column.FieldName = "CurrentFieldBoundToColumn"; So the actual displayvalue of the items gets overwritten.

Comment: Thanks woorking fine, However the action dosent recgonise the new { ID = content.KeyValue }  as a value for the action ; 
public ActionResult GoToTransac(string ID)
{
   //Logic
}

Anny idea why?

TLD;R  It get's routed correctly but the value is not set to the Actionresult functions in parameter

Comment: I think you should create another question for this and post your action and view code.

Comment: Probably true was going abit out of scope there. However i got it woorking now and thanks fo the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    settings.Columns.Add(c =>
    {
        c.FieldName = "Dept_Name"; c.Caption = "Dept Name";
        c.SetDataItemTemplateContent(i =>
        {
            ViewContext.Writer.Write(Html.ActionLink(DataBinder.Eval(i.DataItem, "Dept_Name").ToString(), "Edit", new { Dept_Id = DataBinder.Eval(i.DataItem, "Dept_Id").ToString().Trim() }).ToHtmlString());
        });
    });
```

Comment: hi there, try provide some description of the code. thanks.